# How does this Java initialisation work?

Tags: javafx

Apologies for a newbie question, but my textbooks and web searches are not helping me (probably because I don't know the right name of what I'm looking at). In [some example code](http://www.drdobbs.com/jvm/javafx-custom-controls/226600252?pgno=2), I see a member declaration and initialisation of a `javafx.scene.shape.Rectangle`like this:

```
var bgRect = Rectangle {
    x: 0
    y: 0
    width: bind listView.width
    height: bind this.itemText.boundsInLocal.height 
    fill: bind bgColor; 
}
```

I can see what this is doing, but not how. How does what's inside the braces get turned into a `Rectangle` instance?

Comment: The code you're looking at isn't Java, it's Apache Groovy. It's compatible with Java which is why you see Java imports. See http://groovy-lang.org for more information.

Comment: It's not Groovy either William ;-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not Java, this is a special language that early versions of JavaFX used, called [JavaFX Script](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaFX_Script).

Comment: Well, that certainly explains why I couldn't find it in the Java documentation. Thanks!